# Can "NIC teaming" decrease contention, for multiple sites with separate application pools? (connecting server w/ IIS, and server w/ SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, performance, networking, iis-7, nic

SUMMARY:  if sites have separate application pools, can their traffic avoid contention through "NIC teaming"?

((Let me know if this is better posted on http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com))

DETAILS: 
Our hosting provider has priced a scenario where NIC teaming could be done, between the server hosting our websites, and the server hosting our databases.

Tech details (in case they matter):
(1)  The websites are hosted on a server running Windows Server 2008, with IIS 7.0.
(2)  The databases are hosted on a server running Windows Server 2003, with SQL Server 2005.
(3)  NIC teaming scenario they described would involve each of the two servers having a  10GBE dual-port NIC card, with crossover cables between.
(4)  Each site has its own web.config, and its own application pool in IIS.
(5)  Currently, the connection strings to SQL Server, for each website, all look exactly the same, but we could make each website use a different connection string.

HOWEVER, the hosting provider told us we will only see "bandwidth aggregation" if
(A) Our application is coded to use the NIC teaming (it is not), or
(B) Our communication goes over more than one TCP stream.

So, here's my first 2 questions... call this "PLAN A" --
(I)  because our sites all have separate application pools (detail #4 above -- resulting in "w3wp.exe" appearing over 10 times, in Task Manager), 
would that mean we have more than one TCP stream?

(II) could there be any *effective* decrease in network contention -- that is, could the traffic from the different sites / different application pools travel on separate tNICs?

My third question... call this "PLAN B":
(III) If the answer to both the above is "No", then I still see a possibility of giving *ONE* of our sites a separate SQL Server connection string, to give it a separate NIC, or separate tNIC.  Does *that* make sense?

It sounds like it does, if I'm understanding another post here at StackOverflow:
[.NET SqlConnection NIC usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183557/net-sqlconnection-nic-usage/183649#183649)

But I'd still *PREFER* plan a -- automatic decrease of contention, based on separate application pools -- because I trust a NIC Teaming Solution to direct traffic in a much more intelligent way -- based on varying demand -- than it would be to exclusively dedicate a port to one site's SQL Server.

Please forgive if this is TMI... feedback welcome.

Thanks for your interest...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of application pools does not determine the number of TCP streams. Each HTTP request to your server will be a separate TCP stream, unless a client reuses an existing connection (HTTP keep-alive).

If you are experiencing network contention, using a teamed NIC should help you decrease it. You are creating another physical path to the server, but the router or switch will have to know to use it.

Comment: Thanks much for stepping up!  Makes sense, and I promise to mark as answer... I do have a question (let me know if you'd rather I clarify my question)--my (growing) understanding of SQL Server connections from .NET (our platform) seems like re-using an existing connection. And the hoster said all the sites would be one TCP stream--which I did not mention, because *THAT* made *NO* sense to me.  But I'm hoping (as your answer suggests, and as it makes sense to me) that the application pools' connections would at least represent "separate existing connections".  Thoughts? Thx again!!

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble parsing your question, but I believe that you are asking about the SQL Server connections that your application pools establish. If so, each application pool will establish at least one connection to SQL server (which will be a single TCP stream). If you are opening the connection for each HTTP request or for some collection of SQL batches for each request, then  you may or may not have multiple TCP connections to SQL server (depending on contention for the connection).

Comment: THANKS, William -- I think that NAILS it :)  --Our platform does not open a connection for each HTTP request:  the same .NET connection object is used for all SQL server queries, for that application.  But each website creates a new connection object upon initialization of its application pool.  So, our sites must each have their own connection to the sql server databases... UNLESS there's a possibility that different .NET application pools could SHARE a system-wide connection...?

Comment: No, can't share SQL connections across processes.

Comment: Even if the sites' connection object was defined by "Creating objects in the global namespace..." ?   (quoting one of your comments at [check if app is running already under current user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19411122/check-if-app-is-running-already-under-current-user/19411304#19411304) :)

Comment: C# for SqlConnection: 
'namespace System.Data.SqlClient
{
    //     Represents an open connection to a SQL Server database. This class cannot
    //     be inherited.
    [DefaultEvent("InfoMessage")]
    public sealed class SqlConnection : DbConnection, ICloneable
    {
        //     Initializes a new instance of the System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection class.
        public SqlConnection();
        //     Initializes a new instance of the System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection class
        //     when given a string that contains the connection string.'

Comment: The namespace I'm referring to there is Windows Kernel object namespace, which is an entirely different beast. Here namespace refers to a way to group types.

Comment: THANK you, TY, ty... much appreciated.  Found some of your best answers elsewhere to upvote, in appreciation.

Comment: FYI, William -- our website hosting provider has confirmed your analysis... but first, I used your analysis as backup, to contend that their "first level" rep had given a questionable answer.  It was their higher-level rep who understood this as you did.  *AS A RESULT*, they are open to setting up NIC Teaming for us for BANDWIDTH AGGREGATION, where before, they were only offering NIC Teaming for higher availability.  So, THANKS AGAIN.